# How I can open dynamic created html page in IE without saving (C# + API or COM)

Tags: c#, html, api, dynamic, com

**Hello!**

How can i open dynamic generated html page in IE with it API or COM? 
*Problem is that it page haven't real link address...*
I cannot save file to disk or to clipboard on assignment.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this link for an example of constructing an html page from scratch in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument).  You ought to be able to do something similar, inserting all the html that you already seem to have (previously generated), as the html of the new document.